# What code do I wrap around Lua code in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax, lua, luabind

I finally got LuaBind configured to work with my C++ project. I recently found out that the Tiled map editor has an option to export the files as a .lua, so I wanted to try it out. What code would I wrap around the pasted code below to have it work with my C++ RPG project?

```
return {
  version = "1.1",
  luaversion = "5.1",
  orientation = "orthogonal",
  width = 24,
  height = 20,
  tilewidth = 16,
  tileheight = 16,
  properties = {},
  tilesets = {
    {
      name = "PALLET TOWN",
      firstgid = 1,
      tilewidth = 16,
      tileheight = 16,
      spacing = 0,
      margin = 0,
      image = "PALLET TOWN.bmp",
      imagewidth = 384,
      imageheight = 320,
      properties = {},
      tiles = {}
    }
  },
  layers = {
    {
      type = "tilelayer",
      name = "Tile Layer 1",
      x = 0,
      y = 0,
      width = 24,
      height = 20,
      visible = true,
      opacity = 1,
      properties = {},
      encoding = "lua",
      data = {
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
        25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48,
        49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72,
        73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96,
        97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120,
        121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144,
        145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 150, 151, 152, 153, 154, 155, 156, 157, 158, 159, 160, 161, 162, 163, 164, 165, 166, 167, 168,
        169, 170, 171, 172, 173, 174, 175, 176, 177, 178, 179, 180, 181, 182, 183, 184, 185, 186, 187, 188, 189, 190, 191, 192,
        193, 194, 195, 196, 197, 198, 199, 200, 201, 202, 203, 204, 205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210, 211, 212, 213, 214, 215, 216,
        217, 218, 219, 220, 221, 222, 223, 224, 225, 226, 227, 228, 229, 230, 231, 232, 233, 234, 235, 236, 237, 238, 239, 240,
        241, 242, 243, 244, 245, 246, 247, 248, 249, 250, 251, 252, 253, 254, 255, 256, 257, 258, 259, 260, 261, 262, 263, 264,
        265, 266, 267, 268, 269, 270, 271, 272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 278, 279, 280, 281, 282, 283, 284, 285, 286, 287, 288,
        289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294, 295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312,
        313, 314, 315, 316, 317, 318, 319, 320, 321, 322, 323, 324, 325, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 331, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336,
        337, 338, 339, 340, 341, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360,
        361, 362, 363, 364, 365, 366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 371, 372, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 383, 384,
        385, 386, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 402, 403, 404, 405, 406, 407, 408,
        409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 419, 420, 421, 422, 423, 424, 425, 426, 427, 428, 429, 430, 431, 432,
        433, 434, 435, 436, 437, 438, 439, 440, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 447, 448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454, 455, 456,
        457, 458, 459, 460, 461, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 471, 472, 473, 474, 475, 476, 477, 478, 479, 480
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.  I'm trying to find out what to wrap this code with to paste it into my C++ code.

Comment: That's just a lua data file, it returns a table with the map data in it.  You would need to supply whatever code you want to parse the data.

Comment: Do you mean you're looking to `#include` this lua file into your C++ source somehow? Or are you just looking for a way to load that lua script from your C++ code?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "*have it work*". How are you looking to integrate and use it?

Comment: Do you want to embed lua into your C++ program so that you can read lua files, instantiate objects and use those objects in your C++ code?

Comment: You would read the file using `lua_load`, call it with `lua_call` and then use `lua_getfield` to get the values from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Warning: My answer might be nooby since I'm the kind prefer more work and less complicates.

first, remove the `return` and {} that belong to the return.
now put it to a place that your program can find it.

now come to the luabind part(luabind is not really necessary for this kind of job, but i will use it since it's a good practice for you).

let's see your main program that uses these values is called `stage`
and there is a loader method called `load`.
Start with the header:

```
extern "C"
{
    #include <lua.h>
    #include <lualib.h>
    #include <lauxlib.h>
}
#include ".\luabind\luabind.hpp"
#include <iostream>

class Stage
{
    public:
        Stage();
        Stage(string stage_name);
        // the methods that stage use to run
        static void _load(<a table of input
           or whatever the way you want to transfer the information>,
                          intptr_t stage);/* static for luabind intptr_t is designed 
              to hold pointer in int form.*/
        void load(<a table of input or whatever the way you want to transfer the information>);
        ~Stage();

    private:
        //lot of values that you want.

}
```

And in the cpp file, you well want load in the start of the game:

```
    void _load(<a table of input
       or whatever the way you want to transfer the information> table,
       intptr_t stage)
    {
        Stage* stage = (Stage*)stg; // intptr_t back to pointer
        stage->load(table);
    }

    void Stage:load(<a table of input
       or whatever the way you want to transfer the information> table)
    {
        <load infos into your variable>
    }

    Stage(string stage_name)
    {

        intptr_t stage = (intptr_t)*this;
        // Create a new lua state
        lua_State *myLuaState = luaL_newstate();

        // Connect LuaBind to this lua state
        luabind::open(myLuaState);
        luaL_openlibs(myLuaState);

        luabind::module(myLuaState)[
        luabind::def("load", &_load) 
        ];

        luabind::globals(myLuaState)["stage"] = stage;// give the pointer to lua

        stringstream fileadd << <candidate address here>;
        lual_dofile(myLuaState, fileadd);
        lua_close(myLuaState);/we don't need lua anymore/

        <start your game>
     }
```

Example of lua:

```
    <your origin file without return>
    <put it into a table or something>
    -- load is a callable file after it's launched with your stage cpp 
    -- stage is the pointer that passed to lua
    load(<table of information>, stage)
```

It's up to you how to pass the variables, but I think this method should works fine, just lots works?

[More information about pointer and luabind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213495/rather-then-create-a-object-in-lua-how-let-lua-directly-tall-the-c-object-to)